# IndexOutOfBoundsException when adding achartengine's doughnutchartview to a linear layout

Tags: android, achartengine, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to show a doughnut chart in my activity. In fact my activity consists of some fragments. So it does not extend Activity but it extends FragmentActivity.
I am using achartengine's doughnutchartview to integrate a doughnut chart inside the activity (not inside it's fragment) by adding it to a linear layout. The linear layout is already defined in a xml layout file. This is my code:

Activity:

```
public class FoodConfessionsActivity extends FragmentActivity { 
    GraphicalView mChartView;
    DefaultRenderer mRenderer;
    MultipleCategorySeries mSeries;
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mChartView == null) {
            LinearLayout chart1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart1);
            List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
            values.add(new double[] { 12, 14, 11, 10, 19 });
            values.add(new double[] { 10, 9, 14, 20, 11 });
            List<String[]> titles = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            titles.add(new String[] { "P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5" });
            titles.add(new String[] { "Project1", "Project2", "Project3", "Project4", "Project5" });
            int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.YELLOW, Color.CYAN };
            mSeries = new MultipleCategorySeries("ideal");
            int k = 0;
            for (double[] value : values) {
                mSeries.add(2007 + k + "", titles.get(k), value);
                k++;
            }
            mRenderer = new DefaultRenderer();
            mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
            mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(222, 222, 200));
            mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.GRAY);
            mRenderer.setStartAngle(180);
            mRenderer.setDisplayValues(true);
            mChartView = ChartFactory.getDoughnutChartView(getApplicationContext(), mSeries, mRenderer);
            chart1.addView(mChartView); // Exception occurs at this line

        } else {
           mChartView.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
...
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/chart1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
...
```

My problem is that an IndexOutOfBoundsException will be thrown after reaching this line in activity class (as i have specified in the code above):

```
chart1.addView(mChartView);
```

and the application will be closed.
I searched alot and could not figure out what is my mistake? Can any one help?

Edited: And this is my log cat:

```
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at org.achartengine.renderer.DefaultRenderer.getSeriesRendererAt(DefaultRenderer.java:189)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at org.achartengine.chart.DoughnutChart.draw(DoughnutChart.java:109)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at org.achartengine.GraphicalView.onDraw(GraphicalView.java:168)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10978)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2887)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10981)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2887)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10981)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2887)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10981)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2126)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2026)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1634)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-16 09:38:26.854: E/AndroidRuntime(25648):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanx alot in advance.

Comment: You need to post the full logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `MultipleCategorySeries`, but you don't have any `SimpleSeriesRenderer` added to the `mRenderer`. See [this](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/BudgetDoughnutChart.java) for an example.